# How to get Data About Phone Number and Locations

Tags: java, android, location, phone-number

I developed an application that shows the Location and service provider of any phone Number.

Like `9718202569`         Idea number Delhi Telecom Circle

I did that for All Indian phone Numbers.

Now I want to do it for US, UK and other countries phone Number.

But I am not getting data on internet related to this.

Comment: Just for curiosity, Have you used country code anywhere in your code to achieve the goal for indian numbers ?

Answer (score 4):

See this:

```
    telephonyManager =  (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lineOne = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
    Log.d(TAG, "line 1 " + lineOne);

    deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); 
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceId() " + deviceId);


    networkOperator =  telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
    Log.d(TAG, "getNetworkOperatorName() " + networkOperator);

    networkType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    Log.d(TAG, "getNetworkType () " + networkType);

    phoneType = telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
    Log.d(TAG, "getPhoneType () " + phoneType);

    simSerialNumber = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
    Log.d(TAG, "getSimSerialNumber () " + simSerialNumber );

    subscriberId = telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
    Log.d(TAG, "getSubscriberId () " + subscriberId);


    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, timeBetweenFixes, distanceBetweenFixes, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, timeBetweenFixes, distanceBetweenFixes, locationListener);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    context.registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: This only give the Info about SIM in Phone. I want this info for all phone numbers

Comment: You asking about contacts??